How can I generate a cross-reference in pdf for a table that is an output from the modelsummary R package?
I wrote the R Markdown chunk below and the output pdf is showing Table ??. I haven't found a way to solve this problem. I checked the answer given in this post, but the question is not pdf related.
---
title: 'A title'
author: "Me"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    dev: cairo_pdf
    toc: false
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{mathptmx}
  - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
lang: ES-es
linkcolor: red
---

Results are shown in Table \@ref(tab:table1)

```{r table1, echo=FALSE}
modelsummary(model_list,
             escape = TRUE,
             shape = term ~ model + statistic,
             estimate = "estimate",
             statistic = c("std.error", "p.value"),
             gof_map = c("aic"),
             coef_rename = c("anchura" = "Anchura",
                             "peso" = "Peso",
                             "color_f3" = "Color medio",
                             "color_f4" = "Color medio oscuro",
                             "color_f5" = "Color oscuro",
                             "estado_espina_f2" = "Estado regular",
                             "estado_espina_f3" = "Estado malo"),
             title = "Results")

```

I tried with the trick: title = "\\label{fig:table1}" and knit three times but didn't work.

One possible option would be to use title = "(\\#tab:table1)Results" and set escape=FALSE.
Using the default example from modelsummary:
---
title: 'A title'
author: "Me"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    dev: cairo_pdf
    toc: false
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{mathptmx}
  - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
lang: ES-es
linkcolor: red
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(modelsummary)
```

```{r include=FALSE}
url <- "https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/HistData/Guerry.csv"
dat <- read.csv(url)
dat$Small <- dat$Pop1831 > median(dat$Pop1831)
dat <- dat[
  ,
  c("Donations", "Literacy", "Commerce", "Crime_pers", "Crime_prop", "Clergy", "Small")
]

model_list <- list(
  "I" = lm(Donations ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat),
  "II" = lm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat),
  "III" = lm(Crime_prop ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat),
  "IV" = glm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Commerce, family = poisson, data = dat),
  "V" = glm(Donations ~ Literacy + Commerce, family = poisson, data = dat)
)
```

Results are shown in Table \@ref(tab:table1)

```{r table1, echo=FALSE}
modelsummary(model_list,
  escape = FALSE,
  estimate = "estimate",
  statistic = c("std.error", "p.value"),
  gof_map = c("aic"),
  title = "(\\#tab:table1)Results"
)
```


Quarto:
And just in case and as a reference: As mentioned by @Vincent in the comments, when using quarto one could add the table caption using the tbl-cap option instead of using the title= argument of modelsummary():
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
lang: ES-es
linkcolor: red
editor: visual
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(modelsummary)
```

```{r include=FALSE}
url <- "https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/HistData/Guerry.csv"
dat <- read.csv(url)
dat$Small <- dat$Pop1831 > median(dat$Pop1831)
dat <- dat[
  ,
  c("Donations", "Literacy", "Commerce", "Crime_pers", "Crime_prop", "Clergy", "Small")
]

model_list <- list(
  "I" = lm(Donations ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat),
  "II" = lm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat),
  "III" = lm(Crime_prop ~ Literacy + Clergy, data = dat),
  "IV" = glm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Commerce, family = poisson, data = dat),
  "V" = glm(Donations ~ Literacy + Commerce, family = poisson, data = dat)
)
```

Results are shown in @tbl-table1

```{r echo=FALSE}
#| label: tbl-table1
#| tbl-cap: Results
modelsummary(model_list,
  estimate = "estimate",
  statistic = c("std.error", "p.value"),
  gof_map = c("aic")
)
```



Great answer. Just a footnote: In Quarto, it is sometimes better to use the Quarto code chunks to specify captions and labels, rather than using the title argument in modelsummary() directly.

Thx @Vincent. Added the quarto use case as a reference.
